# How to overwrite printed one liners in Python?

Tags: python-3.7

I am currently working on a random password generator which will generate a new password every 10 seconds. I know how to time loop the program but the problem is I don't want the previous password to stay on screen when a new one is generated.

The code is:

```
import random , time
while True:
    for i in range(6):
        print(random.randint(0,9), end=" ")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(" ")
```

The output is:

```
Output1
Output2
etc.
```

I want the Output2 to overwrite Output1
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Hunter McMillen for the edit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to print with `end='\r'` (carriage return).

```py
while True:
    for i in range(6):
        print(random.randint(0, 9), end=" ")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(end="\r")
```

By default, [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) uses `end='\n'` (new line) as the default. By changing it to carriage return, you force it to rewind the cursor to the start of the line. As long as the next line being printed is of the same length, it overwrites the previous one.

Comment: Bro , thank you so much ! I've been searching for this answer for ages , found a lot of complicated codes our there but none worked for me , thank you so much !!